# Generics: Create instance from abstract class

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to create an instance of a class, but the compile-time error is saying:

> Cannot create an instance of the abstract class 'QueueProcess'.

However, I am not creating an instance of it, I am creating an an instance of a class that extends `QueueProcess`. So, why am I getting this error?

```
export class Queue<T extends QueueProcess> {

    private _queue: T[] = []

    private async runFirstProcess() {
      let process = new this._queue[0]
    }

}

export abstract class QueueProcess {

}
```

The code once compiled works fine, it is just throwing that compile-time error.

Comment: isn't new T of type QueueProcess, not the derived type?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean...

Comment: Shouldn't it be,at least, `export class Queue extends QueueProcess implements T`. It seems really weird while you are using that "arrows" around extends

Comment: because `Queue` doesn't extend `QueueProcess`, it holds an array of `QueueProcess`'s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, first of all, the line `T extends QueueProcess` means that T is an *instance* of QueueProcess, which won't be newable. To access the constructor type, you need `T extends typeof QueueProcess`.

But that won't work anyway, since QueueProcess itself extends QueueProcess, and since it's abstract, typescript will complain about that. So instead, make T extend a newable function that returns a QueueProcess, eg:

```
export class Queue<T extends new () => QueueProcess> {

    private _queue: T[] = []

    private async runFirstProcess() {
        let process = new this._queue[0]()
    }

}

export abstract class QueueProcess {

}
```

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I didn't know that you could do `<T extends new() => xxx>`

Comment: `new () => SomeType` is a shorthand syntax for an [interface with construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#difference-between-the-static-and-instance-sides-of-classes), also called "newable type": `{new(): SomeType}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the `Constructor` helper](https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest/blob/main/source/basic.d.ts#L13) from [type-fest](https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest):

```
export class Queue<T extends Constructor<QueueProcess>> {

    private _queue: T[] = []

    private async runFirstProcess() {
        let process = new this._queue[0]()
    }

}

export abstract class QueueProcess {

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I rewrote your code a bit to satisfy the code analyzer. It's placed [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=export%20abstract%20class%20QueueProcess%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20class%20Queue%3CT%3E%20extends%20QueueProcess%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20_queue%3A%20T%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20async%20runFirstProcess()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20process%20%3D%20new%20this._queue%5B0%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D). However, your code has issue with `new this._queue[0]`. Also, extension of class that is placed after current is a bad idea.

Result code is

```
export abstract class QueueProcess {

}

export class Queue<T> extends QueueProcess {

    private _queue: T[] = []

    private async runFirstProcess() {
      let process = new this._queue[0]
    }

}
```